# Prove language is not regular?

Tags: regular-languages, proof-techniques

I know how to use the pumping lemma to do so, but I don't think that can be used for this language:

$$L = \{x \in \{0,1\}^* : \text{no prefix of $x$ has more $1$'s than $0$'s}\}. $$

What other method can I use to prove this?

Comment: The pumping lemma should be enough. Think about what the prefix condition tells you about the whole string.

Comment: can I use a pumping length p? or is that too general? If can use p you could just do (0^p-1)1 and pump 1 p times

Comment: That looks like the right approach, yes. If the language was regular, there would be a pumping length. The pumping length is essentially the number of states of some automaton that accepts the language, so you can't choose it: that means you have to be general and just let it be $p$.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at our reference question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $0^n1^n$ for large enough $n$.

Another approach is to use the Myhill-Nerode criterion, say with the words $0^n$.